# Is "swung along the corner" possible?

Tags: sentence-construction

Imagine an empty warehouse. You drive along the wall inside the warehouse and then you swing in the corner of it. Is there a way to describe taking a corner not going around it but inside it? Is this possible:

He swung along the corner.

?

Comment: I'm not sure if I am picturing things correctly, but "**swung along** the corner" definitely doesn't sound right.  *Along* usually means something like following a line (as in "He drove along the wall") but a corner isn't a line.

Comment: You can go around, or turn a corner inside or outside.